# Eclipse as an applet?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to run eclipse without downloading, installing, unpacking or even having the file on the computer, to use it like a applet in the browser?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe we can come up with other solutions for your problem.

Comment: @cyroxx Its not a problem, I want to use Eclipse in school and I don't want to bring a pen drive with me, but I guess I have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing how Eclipse contains native code (the SWT), I'm gonna say: No.

Maybe using something like Remote Desktop (but that doesn't count, does it).